# How to get the most common record per ID in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 20k records and 650 unique IDs. I want to obtain the most common record for each ID using `mode()`.

Data:

```py
 ID Device Country Region City
100    Win       A      X    P
100    Win       A      X    P
100    Win       A      X    P
200    Mac       B      Y    Q
200    Mac       B      Y    Q
300  Linux       C      Z    R
300  Linux       C      Z    R
```

Desired outcome:

```py
 ID Device Country Region City
100    Win       A      X    P
200    Mac       B      Y    Q
300  Linux       C      Z    R
```

I have written this code to get the desired result, but it gives zero records:

```py
for id in df.groupby('id'):
    df_new = pd.DataFrame() #creating blank dataframe 
    df_new['Device'] = df['Device'].mode()[0]
    df_new['Country'] = df['Country'].mode()[0]
    df_new['Region'] = df['Region'].mode()[0]
    df_new['City'] = df['City'].mode()[0]
```

Comment: Something I'm noticing is that you never set the `id` in the `for` loop, however, generally speaking looping should be a last resort. There's almost always a built-in way to process tabular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```py
df.groupby("ID").apply(pd.DataFrame.mode).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```py
    ID Device Country Region City
0  100    Win       A      X    P
1  200    Mac       B      Y    Q
2  300  Linux       C      Z    R
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your code, it has introduced some NaN values in between records and the total record count is 1210 inplace of 650. also what is drop=True here?

Comment: Can you confirm that `len(df.groupby("ID"))`  is indeed 650? What is the dtype of the `ID` column?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try `df.groupby("ID")[["Device", "Country", "Region", "City"]].apply(pd.DataFrame.mode).droplevel(1).reset_index()` but that should return the same thing.

Comment: For an explanation of `drop=True`, see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).